# Unlocking a broken-screen Nexus 6

Tags: factory-reset, broken-screen, password, nexus-6

I have a pretty stock Nexus 6. It has Full Disk Encryption turned on, AFAIK (I didn't change any settings from when I first got it, and it requires the PIN to boot up). I dropped it yesterday, during which time the screen completely died and the phone rebooted.

The screen is just plain black, and as far as I can tell is also not registering any touches (no tactile feedback, etc). The phone is now in the "waiting to boot" mode where it ticks every second to remind me to enter my PIN.

I've already ordered a new phone, but I'd like to wipe this one before I recycle it. Has anyone had any luck with alternative methods of entering data into the phone? All I really need to do is get the PIN entered so it can boot up. Then (hopefully) it'll find service or WiFi, at which point I can send a remote wipe command. It's just that I can't do anything over USB while it's still partly booted the way it is.

Comment: `the screen is just plain black`, yet you see `waiting to boot` but `ticks every second to remind` you to enter `PIN`, thus if `not registering any touches` how can the pin be entered?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to enter the PIN on that phone if you cannot use the touch screen. The only thing you would be able to do to that phone now is doing the "hard master reset" by pressing the button combination for that phone. That would also delete all the data stored on that phone.

To find the master reset button combination for that phone, try using Google or going to XDA Developers.

Comment: FWIW, I had hoped to either recycle or resell the nexus. I'm not wild about just destroying it outright, which is what I had done to earlier phones I owned. I did find the hard master reset combo for the nexus6, but of course there's no feedback on the screen (or audible) that this has occurred. Alas.