# Nexus 6P - how to retrieve data with a locked phone and broken screen?

Tags: backup, broken-screen, nexus-6p

I've smashed my phone screen and it is unresponsive and completely black, displaying nothing. The phone has also been powered off, meaning instead of my finger print for unlocking, I have to put in the pin in order for the phone to fully boot up. I do know my pin however, cannot enter it.

Does anybody have any hints or perhaps know how to get into the phone (with my Mac) to try and back up my data to the computer so I can transfer it to my new phone?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide :) would really appreciate it!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform a full system dump/backup with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54272/how-to-perform-a-full-system-dump-backup-with-a-broken-screen)

Comment: You use the [tag:broken-screen], but have you looked through it's [tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)? Also, you could try a site search filtering by the tags you use.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but no sadly not! I have spent some time searching, yes but have found nothing. Difference in my situation is the phone has been restarted, and therefore does not fully boot-up until you enter the pin at the start and is thus not detectable by adb.

Comment: There are questions addressing exactly that problem too. As it turns out, there is some hacky way to use ADB to enter the boot PIN itself! Lets see if I can find it, 36000 questions tend to mean some get lost.

Comment: You could try [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75248/s3-screen-broken-developer-mode-on-how-to-transfer-data/132027#132027), [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62210/how-to-add-a-custom-lock-for-the-recovery-and-or-bootloader/62225#62225), [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67352/how-to-backup-broken-screen-phone-when-usb-debugging-is-not-enabled/120564#120564) or [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137821/unlocking-a-broken-screen-nexus-6). Let me know if it helps!